# UILocalNotifications: any way to make them inactive without deleting/de-scheduling them?

Tags: iphone, arrays, uilocalnotification

I've been asked to work some alarm functionality, very similar to the Alarms functionality of the iPhone's clock, into an application.

I see from the documentation that there are fire dates and ways to use the alert body as a label and all that good stuff. But if you wanted to mark an alarm as being "OFF" with a switch or inactive, is there a UILocalNotification property I could exploit for this purpose, to keep the notification in UIApplication scheduledLocalNotifications, but not fire (or at least, be hidden)? It seems like the only way to not have a notification fire when an application is in the background is to delete or unschedule it altogether, in which case my table view would no longer have the alarm/notification data to keep in display and mark as ON or OFF.

I hate to think I have to maintain alarms data in the app redundantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the `alertBody` and `soundName` to `nil`. If that doesn’t work, you’re probably stuck keeping a redundant copy of the alarm data.

Comment: I think you're right. I somehow missed what the documentation says this about the alertBody property: "Assign a string or, preferably, a localized-string key (using NSLocalizedString) as the value of the message. If the value of this property is non-nil, an alert is displayed. The default value is nil (no alert)."

Comment: It looks like I'll have to keep redundant data, as I want to retain alarms information in a list, even though a notification that has fired will be descheduled and removed from scheduledLocalNotifications, and thus my table view. But, it's still good to know about setting alertBody to nil.